# OrientDB: How get duplicated values in class?

Tags: sql, orientdb

I started using orientedb yesterday and still do not understand very well. I have a person class with the name, age and eye color keys. I want to find the names of people who have the same eye colors. I already put a distinct to check what the different colors are, however I have more than 100000 data, and I can not find it by selecting the hand. What SQL script can I write to find the names of these people?

Comment: What have you tried yet? What is the expected output?

Comment: I just tried the "distinct" function, not more else. My expected output is like this:
for eye_color green
name                             
John
Mark
Carl
...

Comment: Do you need all the names in a single row or in different rows?

Comment: Different rows, I think is better

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this might be one of the beginning lessons of SQL. You need a where clause like below:

```
Select name from person where eyecolor = 'Green'
```